# How to get a slack user by email using users.info API?

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to use Slack's `users.info` API to retrieve users information, but I need to find users by email, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 23):

Yes!

`https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail`

Using this we can find a user if email id is available.

More : https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail

Answer (score 16):

Currently you can only look up users with `users.info` by their ID.

An alternative solution to your problem would be to call [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) and filter within your client by the `profile.email` for whichever email you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

An undocumented API can do this job:
https://slack.com/api/auth.findUser?team=&email=&token=xoxp-XXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 4):

If this is being done on behalf of a Slack slash command, one can configure the command to expand `@username`, `#channels`, etc...

This can be done under the command section of the Slack app. See the following screenshot:

[image: Slack app config: expand usernames and channels]

Comment: Thanks. Here is a regular expression to find and parse the escaped usernames:  
`\<@([^\|]+)\|([^\>]+)\>`

Answer (score 2):

You should use this scope **users:read.email**, the **users:read** is no longer a sufficient scope for email field.

Check this to get more infos: https://api.slack.com/scopes/users:read.email

That's worked for me as wanted !

Answer (score 2):

This was useful for me. 
My setup: I am part of an enterprise, so the `legacy token` does not have `users:read.email` scope to it.

Solution: I created an app with `users:read.email` scope and other scopes needed. Got the app approved from my admin, installed the app to my workspace, retrieved the OAuth token, used it with `https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail`.

Answer (score 2):

**Slack API call through HTTPS get requests method**

- You need to pass token of your chat bot
- In this function you do not need to install libraries like slack_sdk and slack.errors, just call Slack API through https

```
def get_userid_by_email(email:'Enter the user email added on Channel'):
    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer chat_bot_token',
        "type": "url_verification"
    }
    response = requests.get(url = "https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email="+email,
        headers=headers
    )
    return ""+response.json().get('user',{}).get('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the userid with message.user from main calling method

```
 getUsername(userID).then((output) => { username = output.user.name });


function getUsername(userid){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //get token from https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info
        options.uri = "https://slack.com/api/users.info?token=********&userid=" +userid+ "&pretty=";
         rp(options).then(function (body) {
            resolve(body);
            console.log('Retrieved Info slack --- ' + JSON.stringify(body));
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
             resolve(err);
             console.log('aborted - slack ' + JSON.stringify(err));
       });
   });
}
```

refer link : https://github.com/hassifow/Slack.API-User.info/blob/master/LambdaFunction.js

Answer (score 0):

https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail

[image]

```
POST https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email=seunggabi@gmail.com

form-data
token=xoxb-############-#############-$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```